# mafdr returns very small q-values

Tags: matlab, false-discovery-rate

I am using matlab function for FDR procedure. The function is mafdr().

```
p =

    0.4230    0.5940    0.5390    0.6130    0.9000    0.7420    0.4210    0.5210    0.5670    0.6200
>> [f,q]=mafdr(p);
>> q

q =

   1.0e-15 *

    0.5163    0.5163    0.5163    0.5163    0.5995    0.5492    0.5163    0.5163    0.5163    0.5163
```

The results obviously don't make since as they q-values are way too small. what am I missing?

thanks